# 'HdyViewSwitcherBar' is invalid object type?

Tags: python, gtk, arm64, meson-build, flatpak

I'm trying to firgure out how to make a simple GTK+libhandy application for use with my PinePhone. After configuring and testing libhandy in my development environment, everything seemed to work ok (at least in the editor) until I tried to launch it. The window opens and hangs as an essentially empty window and spits this in terminal:

```
Error building template class 'MusikWindow' for an instance of type 'MusikWindow': .:233:1 Invalid object type 'HdyViewSwitcherBar'
```

I think it may have to do with my usage of GTK composite templates, but I have no idea.

I'm under the impression I've correctly configured libhandy to be used in my development environment as I can use the widgets in Glade and they are visible and work properly until I hit run. libhandy has already been noted in the meson.build and the flatpak json.

Comment: Have you made sure to call [`Handy.init()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Handy-0.0/functions.html%23Handy.init) at the beginning of your program?